# Performance issue on reading http request body

Tags: node.js, performance, http

I use the following code snippet to read (without any parsing) HTTP request's body:

```
'use strict'

const http = require('http')

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.time('read')

    const body = []

    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk)
    })
    req.on('end', () => {
        console.timeEnd('read')

        console.log(Buffer.concat(body).toString())
        res.write('OK')
        res.end()
    })
}).listen(3000)
```

Body is quite simple: `{"n":"v"}`. According to the `read` timer it takes more then 200ms on my windows 7 host and about 40-50ms on ubuntu host. IMHO 200ms is too long for such requests.

What the reason of this problem, especially on win host, and is it possible to fix it?

Comment: FYI, this is taking a lot less time on my system (Win10, ssd, i5).. read: 0.922ms
{"n":"v"}
read: 0.125ms
{"n":"v"}
read: 0.095ms
{"n":"v"}.. maybe there is something bad with your Windows 7 machine? I'd suggest perhaps trying another Windows device if you have access!

Comment: @TerryLennox me too

Comment: i tried on my system win 10 , it taking ~100ms

Comment: Thank you. It was a network issue.